# IMDB API - get data about multiple movies

Tags: xml, imdb

Do you know if it's possible to get data of many movies (not just one at the time) with the use of IMDB API (http://www.omdbapi.com/)? Example with one movie only:

Request:

```
http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=requiem+for+a+dream&y=&plot=short&r=xml
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root response="True"><movie title="Requiem for a Dream" year="2000" rated="R" released="27 Oct 2000" runtime="102 min" genre="Drama" director="Darren Aronofsky" writer="Hubert Selby Jr. (based on the book by), Hubert Selby Jr. (screenplay), Darren Aronofsky (screenplay)" actors="Ellen Burstyn, Jared Leto, Jennifer Connelly, Marlon Wayans" plot="The drug-induced utopias of four Coney Island people are shattered when their addictions become stronger." language="English" country="USA" awards="Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 32 wins & 47 nominations." poster="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMzM2OTYwMTY4Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjU1Njg3OA@@._V1_SX300.jpg" metascore="68" imdbRating="8.4" imdbVotes="456,416" imdbID="tt0180093" type="movie"/></root>
```

Answer (score 3):

omdb provides a search parameter so you can get similar upto 9 movies like this

```
www.omdbapi.com/?s=requiem
```

If you are not satisfied with this one, you can also try the imdb's own undocumented search function which seems a bit faster.

```
http://www.imdb.com/xml/find?q=requim
```

Once you have the title / imdbid from the search, you can get more details from the omdb title based query as mentioned in the question.

`

Comment: Now it's also possible to request pages:

`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Batman&page=2&r=XML`

Comment: when we fetch using `http://www.omdbapi.com/?type=movie&r=json&s=Batman&page=2` we get only limited data is there a way to get all the data for a movie in the movie list